# tail events and tail sigma-field

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working on tail-events.

I have a sequence $(X_{n})_{n}$ of random variables. Let $\tau$ be its $\sigma$-field.

From this, I defined $G_n:=\sigma (X_n,X_{n+1},...)$, so that $\tau = \bigcap_{n\geq 1}{G_n}$.

Now I should say if the event {$X_n \rightarrow \infty$} is in $\tau$, but I have trouble understanding how to check if a general event is in a tail $\sigma$-field or not.

Does anyone have some advice for checking this?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event $X_n(\omega)\to \infty$ is not influenced by the first values of $X_k(\omega)$, say $k\leqslant K$. Indeed, if $(a_n,n\geqslant 1)$ is a sequence of real numbers, then defining $b_n:=a_{n+K}$, we have $a_n\to \infty$ if and only if $b_n\to \infty$.

So fix $K$ and write $\{X_n\to \infty\}=\{X_{n+K}\to \infty\}$. The event 
$\{X_{n+K}\to \infty\}$ is in $\sigma(X_j,j\geqslant K)$.